# How to use an "or" conditional in an n_distinct function, in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count, grouping

Suppose we start with this data frame:

```
mydat <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(115,115,115,88,88,88,100,100),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
    Status_1 = c(1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1),
    Status_2 = c("Open","Open","Terminus","Open","Open","Closed","Open","Open")
  )

> mydat
   ID Period Status_1 Status_2
1 115      1        1     Open
2 115      2        2     Open
3 115      3        1 Terminus
4  88      1        1     Open
5  88      2        2     Open
6  88      3        3   Closed
7 100      1        2     Open
8 100      2        1     Open
```

Next, we run the following dplyr grouping to sum the number of instances by Period and Status_1, where Status_2 = "Open":

```
mydat %>%
  group_by(Period,Status_1) %>%
  summarize(StatusCount = n_distinct(ID[Status_2 == "Open"]))

  Period Status_1 StatusCount
   <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
1      1        1           2
2      1        2           1
3      2        1           1
4      2        2           2
5      3        1           0
6      3        3           0
```

I've been trying to expand the above `n_distinct()` function to also include Status_2 = "Terminus" (in addition to the "Open" in the above code). I've tried various iterations of "or" conditions, and summing tricks, with no luck yet. Any ideas how to do this?

The result, including the Status_2 = "Terminus", would look like this:

```
Period Status_1 StatusCount
   <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
1      1        1           2
2      1        2           1
3      2        1           1
4      2        2           2
5      3        1           1
6      3        3           0
```

Comment: `n_distinct(ID[Status_2 %in% c("Open", "Terminus")])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you. I added a conditional/logical `or` in the selection.

```
mydat %>% 
      group_by(Period,Status_1) %>% 
      summarize(StatusCount = n_distinct(ID[Status_2 == "Open"|Status_2 == "Terminus"])) %>% 
      ungroup()
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Period'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Period Status_1 StatusCount
   <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
1      1        1           2
2      1        2           1
3      2        1           1
4      2        2           2
5      3        1           1
6      3        3           0
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have been able to solve that, I tried your solution (or something close)  before posting but I must have made some other mistake or typo

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(115,115,115,88,88,88,100,100),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
    Status_1 = c(1,2,1,1,2,3,2,1),
    Status_2 = c("Open","Open","Terminus","Open","Open","Closed","Open","Open")
  )

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Period, Status_1) %>%
  summarize(StatusCount = n_distinct(ID[Status_2 %in% c("Terminus", "Open")]), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Period Status_1 StatusCount
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
#> 1      1        1           2
#> 2      1        2           1
#> 3      2        1           1
#> 4      2        2           2
#> 5      3        1           1
#> 6      3        3           0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>